# Как залить данные в seed.rb из файла?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть таблицы Question, Rubric и Tag.

Логически взаимосвязь описывается вот так.
    Rubric has many Questions
    Question has many Tags

Есть методы заливки данных из seeds.rb-все в принципе работает, да только не создаются поля `rubric_id` и `tag_id`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'


puts "Создаем рубрики"
file  = File.open( File.join(Rails.root,'db/rubr_questions.txt'))

File.foreach(file).with_index do |line, line_num|
    Rubric.create(
            name: line.strip,
            rubric_type: 1)
end

puts "Создаем теги"
file  = File.open( File.join(Rails.root,'db/tags.txt'))

File.foreach(file).with_index do |line, line_num|
    Tag.create(
            name: line.strip)
end



file  = File.open( File.join(Rails.root,'db/questions.xlsx'))

workbook = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]

puts "Создаем вопросы"
workbook.each_row_streaming do |row|
  if (row[0].to_s.empty? || row[2].to_s.empty?)

  else
        question = Question.create(
                title: row[0],
                preview_image: row[1],
                content: row[2],
                user_id: user.id,
                rubric_name: row[3].to_s,
                tag_names:row[4].to_s)

        question.save!
  end

end
```

Модель **Question**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  attr_writer :rubric_name
  attr_writer :tag_names

  belongs_to :rubric

  has_many :question_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :question_tags

  validates_presence_of :title, :content

  def rubric_name(value)
    return if value.blank?
    self.rubric = Rubric.where(name: value.strip).first
  end

  def tag_names=(value)
    return if value.blank?
    self.tags = value.strip.split(',').map { |name| Tag.where(name: name).first}
  end
end
```

Comment: По файлу db/questions.xlsx как-то можно понять, какому вопросы какие рубрики и тэги соответствуют? Можете привести пример как он выглядит?